# I want to code a depth sensor for arduino

Tags: arduino-mega

I want to code a depth sensor for a little sub that i am working on. I want it to submerge to a any certain depth  for example 2ft. The speed of the motor is to increase by 5 until it reaches the set point given. The problem that I am facing is: **whenever it reaches the set example point of 2ft the motor turns off and the sub resurfaces to the top and doesn't hold the depth .**
What I want is that for whatever speed the motor is at for 2ft depth, to maintain its speed and keep the sub submerge at 2ft.

```
#include <MS5837.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MS5837.h"
#include <Servo.h>
MS5837 sensor;
Servo vertical_thruster;

float x;
float error;
int pwm = 1525;
float currentdepth = sensor.depth();       
float recquireddepth = -0.4;  //  set depth u wish to maintain in meters                           

void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);  
     vertical_thruster.attach(6);
     vertical_thruster.writeMicroseconds(1500);
 /////////////////////////////////////////////Bar 30 Configuration ////////////////////////////////////////     
  Serial.println("Starting");  
  Wire.begin();
 while (!sensor.init()) {
    Serial.println("Init failed!");
    Serial.println("Are SDA/SCL connected correctly?");
    Serial.println("Blue Robotics Bar30: White=SDA, Green=SCL");
    Serial.println("\n\n");
    delay(2000);
  }  
  sensor.setModel(MS5837::MS5837_30BA);
  sensor.setFluidDensity(997); // kg/m^3 (freshwater, 1029 for seawater)
}

void loop() {

  sensor.read(); 
  Serial.print("Depth: "); 
  Serial.print(currentdepth); 
  Serial.println("m");
error = (currentdepth) - (recquireddepth) ;

if ( error!=0)
  { pwm +=5;
    vertical_thruster.writeMicroseconds(pwm+=5);
    Serial.println( pwm+=5);
    Serial.print ( " Submerging ");
  }
if ( error=0){
  vertical_thruster.writeMicroseconds(pwm);
  Serial.print ( "  At Depth");
}
else if ( error >-0){
  vertical_thruster.writeMicroseconds(1400);
  Serial.print ( "resurfacing");
  delay(1000);
}
}
```

Comment: Help with what? What is not working as expected and what is the expected result? Are you getting any errors or is something else happening?

Comment: The code compiles and work yes but when it reaches its set value it dont hold the speed to keep it at the depth set

Comment: Please, edit the question to add all the relevant information. One should not need to read all the comments to understand a question. Re “_it dont hold the speed_”: what does it do instead? You should try to give a _complete_ description of the problem.

Comment: question has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <MS5837.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>

MS5837 sensor;
Servo vertical_thruster;

// Variables

float current_depth ;
float set_depth = 0.30 ; //  depth u wish to go in meters 
float PID_error = 0;
float previous_error = 0;
float elapsedTime,  Time , timePrev;
float pwmvertical_thruster;
int PID_value = 0;
int PID_p = 0;
int PID_i = 0;
int PID_d = 0;

//PID constants
float kp = 4.1;         
float ki = 0.03;
float kd = 1.8;




void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
 vertical_thruster.attach(6);
 Time = millis ();
 vertical_thruster.writeMicroseconds(1500);


///Bar 30 Configuration 

 Serial.println("Starting");  
 Wire.begin();
while (!sensor.init()) {
Serial.println("Init failed!");
Serial.println("Are SDA/SCL connected correctly?");
Serial.println("Blue Robotics Bar30: White=SDA, Green=SCL");
Serial.println("\n\n\n");
delay(2000);
 }  
 sensor.setModel(MS5837::MS5837_30BA);
 sensor.setFluidDensity(997); // kg/m^3 (freshwater, 1029 for seawater)
}

void loop() {

// First read the current value of the depth sensor
sensor.read();    
current_depth = sensor.depth();

timePrev = Time; 
Time= millis();
elapsedTime = ( Time - timePrev) / 1000;

// calculate the error between the set depth and current depth  
PID_error =  set_depth - current_depth ;

// Calculate the P Value
 PID_p = kp * PID_error;

// Calculate the i value in a range on +-0.3 

 if (-0.3 < PID_error < 0.3 ) 
  { 
  PID_i = PID_i + (ki * PID_error);
  }

// Calculate the d value 
PID_d = kd*((PID_error - previous_error)/elapsedTime);
// The total PID value 
PID_value = PID_p + PID_i + PID_d; 

// range for the blue robotics esc

 if ( PID_value < -400)
 { 
 PID_value = -400;
  }
  if( PID_value >400)
  { 
 PID_value = 400;
  }
// calcualte the pwm 
 pwmvertical_thruster = (1500 + PID_value) || ( 1500 - PID_value);
if(pwmvertical_thruster < 1500)
 {
  pwmvertical_thruster= 1500;
  }
 if(pwmvertical_thruster > 1900)
  {
   pwmvertical_thruster=1900;
   }
    Serial.print("Depth: "); 
    Serial.print(sensor.depth()); 
    Serial.println(" m");
    vertical_thruster.writeMicroseconds(pwmvertical_thruster);
    Serial. println ( "t\t");
    Serial. println ( pwmvertical_thruster);
     previous_error = PID_error;


   }`
```

Comment: Is this the working code? Is it behaving correctly? (Since you now marked it as correct answer)

Comment: @chrisl it works but I need to get my values right the esc correct . The esc that I am using has 2 Maximum with 1500 equals to stop . 1500 -1900 is Min to Max clockwise and 1500-1100 is min to max counter clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems:

- You are including the MS5837 library twice. That just doesn't pose a problem, because the library has include guards, that make sure it is only included once.
- At global scope you use `float currentdepth = sensor.depth();`, which calls the function `sensor.depth()`. This will be done before the `setup()` function, so at that time the sensor library does not have any valid depth data. So it's useless. You can just set it to zero.
- In your `loop()` you are doing `sensor.read()`, but then you are never actually getting the new depth value from the library. You are just again using `currentdepth` without changing it ever. You should set the variable to the new value by using `currentdepth = sensor.depth();` after the `sensor.read()`.
- You are using the statement `if ( error=0)`. Using only a single `=` means an assigment. So here the variable `error` get's set to zero and the if statement will not compare it so zero. You have to use a double `=`: `if(error == 0)`.
- `if( error >-0)`: Why are you checking for error being greater than MINUS ZERO. Sure, -0 is a valid integer, but mostly senseless. Also it is questionable, if the logic is correct here, since first you check for error being different than zero. Then you check for it being zero and then (if it is not equal zero) you check for it being greater than zero. If `error` really happens to be greater than zero, you will first write `pwm` to the servo and then directly 1400, which is submerging and resurfacing directly after another in only one loop.
- The whole if structure seems quite off. You should rethink the logic of the program.

---

That said, for reaching a set point of whatever kind it is good to use a PID controller, that will get you to the setpoint rather fast and will keep you there. A PID controller can be done in hardware or software. For implementing a software PID controller on Arduino you can use one of the various PID libraries, for example [this one](https://github.com/br3ttb/Arduino-PID-Library). Most libraries also contain examples, that show how to use them.

Comment: Good, through answer. (Voted) I was going to suggest a PID also. You need something that will "hone in on" the target depth and then keep it there. You'll have to tune the PID with the right control values though.

Comment: @chrisl @ Duncan C  I have updated and fixed the code. can you take a look at it ?